# Problems sending NSString variables to a ViewController before it is pushed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, ios

I am having problems sending along 2 NSString variables to a view controller right before it is pushed.

here is some relevent code for pushing the controller:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CommentsViewController *c = [[CommentsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CommentsView" bundle:nil];
    c.subreddit = subreddit;
    c.redditId = [[[list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"id"];
    c.title = [[[list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"title"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:c animated:YES];
    [c release];

    NSLog(@"subreddit: %@", subreddit);
    NSLog(@"redditId: %@", [[[list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"id"]);
}
```

note that printing out the variables via `NSLog` works as expected.

also, the `c.title` assignment seems to work fine, as i can see the title text on the pushed controller.

here(not just here, anywhere) is where i am finding `(null)` when printing the corresponding variables which i have assigned:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"subreddit: %@", subreddit);
    NSLog(@"redditId: %@", redditId);
}

2010-12-30 20:06:17.108 RedditReader[1073:307] subreddit: (null)
2010-12-30 20:06:17.131 RedditReader[1073:307] redditId: (null)
```

`subreddit` has property set as: `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *subreddit;`

Why can't i seem to assign these values correctly so i can use them in the pushed view controller?

How can i assign these values so i can use them in the pushed view controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like your `viewDidLoad` gets called before the variables are set (I don't use nib files so I can't say for sure...). You could make an `init` method that receives those variables, like this:

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)aTitle reddit:(NSString *)aReddit ... {
    self.title = aTitle;
    // ...
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:@"CommentsView" bundle:nil]) {
        // ...
    }
    return self;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: weird how this worked.... i have built several apps in the same exact way, and had no problem.. i'm not sure why this is happening on this project and not the others!!

Answer (score 0):

Override viewWillAppear and you should see your populated variables, viewDidLod is called when uniting from the nib